# How to connect to multiple servers to run the same query?

Tags: linux, ssh

I have 4 servers where we have log files in same pattern. For every serch/query I need to login to all servers one by one and execute the command.

Is it possible to provide some command, so that it will login to all those servers one by one automatically and will fetch the output from each server?

What configuration, settings etc I have to do to make it working.
I am new to Linux Domain.

Comment: How about a tool like csshX (this one runs on Mac OSX), perhaps something similar for Linux? csshX works pretty well, but I do not know a Linux equivalent.

Comment: you can use [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/)

Comment: Use this tool called [SeaLion](https://sealion.com/). Install the agent on these servers once and monitor the outputs of all servers of any command on graphical UI. Its Free!

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/17931/what-is-a-good-modern-parallel-ssh-tool

Comment: I don't want to use any tool. I want to use whatever is available in Linux like ssh, grep, find or whatever is necessary for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your servers are called `eenie`, `meanie`, `minie`, and `moe`, you simply do

```
for server in eenie meanie minie moe; do
    ssh "$server" grep 'intrusion attempt' /var/log/firewall.log
done
```

The `grep` command won't reveal from which server it is reporting a result; maybe replace it with `ssh "$server" sed -n "/intrusion attempt/s/^/$server: /p" /var/log/firewall.log`

Comment: But it should not prompt for the password. Is there any reference or manual which explains such mechanisms or could you explain please :D

Comment: You want to set up public-key authentication, as explained all over the Internet; for example, [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/).

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in your question comments, there are a number of tools to help you in performing a task on multiple machines. I will add to this list and suggest Ansible. It is designed to perform all of the interactions over ssh, in quite a simple manner, and with very little configuration.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible

If you were to have server-1 and server-2 defined in your `~/.ssh/config` file, then the ansible configuration would be as simple as

```
[myservers]
server-1
server-2
```

Then to run a command on the group

```
$ ansible myservers -a uptime
```

Answer (score -1):

Use https://sealion.com. You just have to execute one script and it will install the agent in your servers and start collecting output. It has a convenient web interface to see the output across all your servers.